# Order lines from a text file by number found in a certain spot of the line

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm sorry that I interrupt you in this manner, I'm new to C# and I've been struggling with this problem for days... Maybe it will seem easy for you :)

I have this text file in this format

```
name|ID|domain|grade|verdict
Ryan|502322|Computers|9,33|Undefined
Marcel|302112|Automatics|6,22|Undefined
Alex|301234|Computers|5,66|Undefined
Leo|201122|Automatics|3,22|Undefined
```

How can I sort the text file using any methods (including LINQ) so that the list from the text file will be ordered by domain, and then descending by the grade column? Like this:

```
name|ID|domain|grade|verdict
Marcel|302112|Automatics|6,22|Undefined
Leo|201122|Automatics|3,22|Undefined
Ryan|502322|Computers|9,33|Undefined
Alex|301234|Computers|5,66|Undefined
```

To read the file, I'm using `var Students = File.ReadAllLines(@"filepath");`, I don't know if it's the smartest approach, and then I write using `File.WriteAllLines`

Thanks in advance! Sorry once again, I know it should be easy, but for me is really tuff :(

Comment: I answered you @Gerea Alexandru

Comment: Watch and run my answer.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some thing like this:

```
var students= File.ReadAllLines(@"filepath");
var headers = lines[0];
students = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
var orders = lines.Select(x => x.Split('|'))
    .Select(x => new { Domain = x[2], Grade = int.Parse(x[3].Replace(",", "")), All = x })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Domain).ThenByDescending(x => x.Grade).Select(x => string.Join("|", x.All)).ToList();

orders.Insert(0, headers);
students=orders.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It throws me an error though... Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to 'string[]' at Student.Select

Comment: Hello  @Saeed Esmaeelinejad. ahle Konajjin?

Comment: @Gezgalee Iran! :)

Comment: @Gerea Alexandru please ToArray() to your student list. Tested and works fine

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
private void ReadFile()
{

    char Delimiter = '|';
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\RaftehHa.txt", Encoding.Default);
    List<string[]> FileRows = Lines.Select(line =>
        line.Split(new[] { Delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(FileRows[0].Select(col => new DataColumn() { ColumnName = col }).ToArray());

    FileRows.RemoveAt(0);
    FileRows.ForEach(row => dt.Rows.Add(row));
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = " ID  ASC ";
    dt = dv.ToTable();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

[image: Sorted]

Answer (score 0):

A bit the same as already mentioned above, but as you mention you are new to C#, I have tried to add a little bit of structure to the code, but leaving the completion to you.

```
    public class Data
    {
        public Data(string inputLine)
        {
            var split = inputLine.Split('|');
    
            Name = split[0];
            Id = int.Parse(split[1]);
            Domain = split[2];
            Grade = double.Parse(split[3].Replace(",", "."));
            Verdict = split[4];
        }
        public string Name { get; }
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Domain { get; }
        public double Grade { get; }
        public string Verdict { get; }
    }
    public class DataFile
    {
        public static IEnumerable Read(string fileName)
        {
            var input = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            return input.Skip(1).Select(p => new Data(p)); // skip header
        }
    
        public static void Write(IEnumerable data)
        {
            // todo :)
        }
    }
    
    void Main()
    {
        var input = DataFile.Read(@"C:\Temp\ExampleData.txt");
    
        var result = input.OrderBy(p => p.Domain).ThenByDescending(p => p.Grade);
    
        DataFile.Write(result);
    }
```

Comment: At 'todo' I think that I should type:
```File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\ExampleData.txt",result);```
Thank you so much! The code works as intended! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


enum DomainType {
     Automatics, // 0
     Computers   // 1
}


class Data {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Verdict { get; set; }
     public DomainType Domain { get; set; }
     public Tuple<int, int> Grade { get; set; }
}

public static class Program {
    
    static IEnumerable<Data> FileContent(string path) {
         string line;
         using (var reader = File.OpenText(path)) 
         {
             bool skipHeader = false;
             while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
             {
                  if (!skipHeader) {
                      skipHeader = true;
                      continue;
                  }
                  var fields = line.Split('|');
                  string name = fields[0];
                  int id = int.Parse(fields[1]);
                  var domain = (DomainType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DomainType), fields[2]);
                  var grade = Tuple.Create(int.Parse(fields[3].Split(',')[0]), 
                                           int.Parse(fields[3].Split(',')[1]));
                  string verdict = fields[4];
                  var data = new Data() { 
                      Name = name, Id = id, Domain = domain, Grade = grade, Verdict = verdict };
                 yield return data;
             }
         }
    }
    
    public static void Main() {
        var result = FileContent("path_to_file").OrderBy(data => data.Domain);
        foreach (var line in result) {
            Console.WriteLine(line.Name);
        }
    }
}
```